# what is this Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 error? ios xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a peculiar error when i try speech recognition framework in objective c

Undefined symbols for architecture `arm64`:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in test.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SFSpeechRecognizer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in test.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Most probably you had added Framework complied for Simulator.

Comment: This means that the framework you are trying to link against does not contain symbols for amd_64.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add necessary framework to your project. Check all third party party framework and search its required framework for support. For e.g. if you add `google analytic` then you need to `add CoreData` , `Foundation` etc framework. There is some framework is missing for which third party framework needs.

Or you can-

1. Press `"Cmd+Shift+K"` to clean up, and quit Xcode.
2. Delete the cache Run `"rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData"` 
   in terminal
3. Open the project and re-build it

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: It seemed to work, but now the error changed to 'symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: Linker command failed with exit code 1'

Comment: @JuneWang  Press "Cmd+Shift+K" several time. I will work

Answer (score 0):

Go to build phases -> link binary with libraries and add speech.framework.