# symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, firebase, google-signin

Facing ObjC file reference issue. I tried pod deintegration, removing DerivedData, Cleaning the project, Adding -Objc and $(inherited) FLAGS.

I am using cocoapods, Xcode 9, Swift 4. Please revert if anyone have resolved this issue. [image: Error Description]

Comment: Have you tried Build Settings -> Architechtures -> Standard?

Comment: paste your pod file

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue make your your ".m" implementation files are assigned to the Target Membership:
[image: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64]

Comment: where is that .m file? how do you assign it? I can see lot of .mm files in the , I don't see any .m files in my xcode project

Comment: .m and .mm files are the same.  ".mm" is then the code has c++ as well as Objective-c in it.

Answer (score 2):

For me none of these answers worked, and appeared to cause more problems.

My solution was in terminal trying "pod install" It added a missing file for me and everything was good to go

Answer (score 1):

Try this
Goto Project -> Build setting 
Serach enable bitcode & set it to NO

Comment: No change. same issue.

Comment: Try updating your Pods again and Restart your Xcode. I have faced the same issue and this thing worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check Your `Pod file` that is it targeting your `App Target`?.

May be `Pod` is not targeting your `App Target`. 
This error occurs when you have reference of `File` or `Framework` that is not included in `Target`.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the `AppDelegate` and `OnBoardingViewCtontroller` file in your project.

Just delete to and add it again. When your are adding it again make sure that `Copy If needed` option is checked

This is bcoz if your uncheck this check box then the file reference is created and if you move project the you will get this error.

Comment: Tried it, Same issue

Answer (score 1):

change the Build Configuration from Debug to Release.
Edit Scheme... -> Info -> Run -> Build Configuration

Answer (score 0):

You need to add necessary framework to your project. Check all third party party framework and search its required framework for support. For e.g. if you add `google analytic` then you need to add `CoreData` , `Foundation` etc framework. There is some framework is missing for which third party framework needs.

Or you can-

1. Press `"Cmd+Shift+K"` to clean up, and quit Xcode.
2. Delete the cache Run `"rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData"` 
   in terminal
3. Open the project and re-build it

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49028125/what-is-this-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-error-ios-xcode/49028323#49028323  . It might be helpful for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try Build Active Architecture Only to NO:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pods for UITest and Test projects for the pods was causing the issue. Check for it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are certain function which are declared in .h file but are not implemented in implementation file and they are being called from another class.

Answer (score -1):

It should be -ObjC, not -Objc. Note the upper case C.